# C# invoke group of tasks at specific time

Tags: c#

I've the below code, that worked perfectly with me, and run in parallel, the required tasks at the specific time, that is midnigh in my case

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace COREserver{
    public static partial class COREtasks{   // partial to be able to split the same class in multiple files
         public static async void RunSheduledTasks_12AM(){
                TimeSpan MIDNIGHT = new TimeSpan(0,00,00,00,000); //set when run event (ex. 18:16:53.123)
                DateTime endDate = DateTime.Today.Add(MIDNIGHT);
                if(endDate<DateTime.Now) endDate = endDate.AddDays(1.0);
                while (true)
                {
                    TimeSpan duration = endDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
                    if(duration.TotalMilliseconds <= 0.0)
                    { 
#region MIDNIGHT Tasks  
                        Parallel.Invoke(
                            () => task1(),
                            () => task2(),
                            () => task3()
                        );
#endregion MIDNIGHT Tasks
                        endDate = endDate.AddDays(1.0);
                        continue;
                    }
                    int delay = (int)(duration.TotalMilliseconds/2);
                    await Task.Delay(delay>0?delay:0);
                }
          }
    }
}
```

I found that I need to do the same, with other times period, like start time of the duty (7:00am), mid day, and end of office people time (5:00PM)

Is there a way to avoid re-coding the everthing, something like callback function, so I can call my tasks like something like this:

```
midnight(MIDNIGHT, task1, task2,...)
midday("12:00:00", task5, task6, ..)
```

or something like:

```
switch(time){
  casse MIDNIGHT: .. run task1, task2,..
  case "12:00:00": .. run task5, task6,..
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Why not use `Quartz.NET` or some other well-established scheduling solution?

Comment: You can create different worker classes for each of the tasks and have their schedule time in config. Once your exe starts each worker will initiate and check for their schedule and if it's time to run they will run else go in sleep state untill the next scheduled time. You can also enable disable them based on the config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides using ready solution like Quartz.NET (as suggested by Stephen in the comments to your question), you could simply pass your start time and list of tasks as parameters to your method:

```
public static async void RunSheduledTasks(TimeSpan endTime, params Action[] tasks)
{
    DateTime endDate = DateTime.Today.Add(endTime);
    if (endDate < DateTime.Now) 
        endDate = endDate.AddDays(1.0);
    while (true)
    {
        TimeSpan duration = endDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
        if(duration.TotalMilliseconds <= 0.0)
        { 
            Parallel.Invoke(tasks);
            endDate = endDate.AddDays(1.0);
            continue;
        }
        int delay = (int)(duration.TotalMilliseconds / 2);
        await Task.Delay(delay > 0 ? delay : 0);
    }
}
```

You could then call it like this:

```
await COREtasks.RunSheduledTasks(new TimeSpan(0,00,00,00,000), 
                                 () => Console.WriteLine("Test1"), 
                                 () => Console.WriteLine("Test2"));
```